# Send emails through Mailchimp, but select recipients with queries from my database

Tags: email, mailchimp

I have a database as part of my web app that stores user emails, age, gender, etc.  Is there a way, through the API to send a bulk email to a lsit of users?  Previously I've used their API to create new entries from my database in MailChimp's system, and then we'd segment our users through MailChimp's web application.  The issue is that sending your data to MailChimp has so many issues.  For example, to store a user's age in MailChimp, you have to create an individual "group title" for each age when done thru the API.  You can't just specify that the field "age" is a number and then add whatever you like.  Also, each user selects a city when they sign up through us, and if we add another city to our selection list, you have to manually add it on MailChimp, otherwise you get an error.

So the simplest solution would be if we could do the segmenting on our side and send an email through the API, unless there is another, easy way to do this.  I know that Amazon SES let's you email through an API, but I want other features of MailChimp, such as sent email history, analytics and providing and easy unsubscribe feature for users - Amazon SES doesn't do any of that.

Is there an answer to my conundrum?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com)? It's a newer service from MailChimp that works like SES, but has those incredible MailChimp marketing sensibilities you know and love (open/click tracking, email audit log, plus lots of new stuff.)

It won't connect directly to your data in MailChimp (yet), but it sounds like you've got all the relevant data in your own DB already and can do the segmentation and content generation yourself.

Bonus: you'll also get a discount if you're already a paying MailChimp customer.

Comment: I looked at Mandrill, but my understanding is that it's specifically a transactional email service, meaning it's not good for bulk email.  We need to send the same email to several thousand people at once.

Comment: It's just fine for bulk stuff as well! In fact, lots of provisions have been made in the API to make bulk sending easier and more efficient. Sorry for the confusion! We talk up the transactional side because that's the big blind-spot in MailChimp proper, but Mandrill does it all.